# OpenX performance - how to test it?

Tags: performance, openx

I have configured an OpenX instance and I want to test the performance of the ad delivery - what is the recommended approach for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [document](https://developer.openx.org/wiki/display/DOCS/Performance+Testing) right on the OpenX website about that - OpenX is distributed with a bunch of JMeter scripts. However, using them you will test only the Openx ad delivery performance, and not the performance of the webserver used to deliver the actual banners/flash movies.

Answer (score 2):

using JMeter is a good way of testing openx performance, but you can also use [siege](http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home)
its performance testing tool, the problem with jmeter is its a GUI tool and allocate some memory, but siege is a command line tool and take less memory, you can create multiple random urls for openx with ajs.php(showing ad) and lg.php(adding impression) files and add all urls in file and use that file with siege with random request type, with concurrent request you can easily call this script from multiple servers at a time.